# #HY000View's SELECT contains subquery in the FROM clause

Tags: sql, view

I have a sql request which is working in phpmyadmin but when I try to make Viev I get error:

## HY000View's SELECT contains subquery in the FROM clause

How to avoid using subquery in the FROM clause? Here is the sql:

```
Select tlb_all.BarCode As BarCode,
  Sum(tlb_all.TotalIncomes) As TotalIncomes,
  Sum(tlb_all.TotalOutcomes) As TotalOutcomes,
  Sum(tlb_all.TotalAdjustments) As TotalAdjustments,
  
  Sum(tlb_all.TotalIncomes - tlb_all.TotalOutcomes + tlb_all.TotalAdjustments)
  As Leftover
From (Select tlb1.BarCode As BarCode, Sum(IfNull(tlb1.Quantity,
      0)) As TotalIncomes, Sum(0) As TotalOutcomes, Sum(0) As TotalAdjustments
    From stock_incomes tlb1
    Group By tlb1.BarCode
    UNION
    Select tlb2.BarCode As BarCode, Sum(0) As TotalIncomes,
      Sum(IfNull(tlb2.Quantity, 0)) As TotalOutcomes, Sum(0) As
      TotalAdjustments
    From stock_outcomes tlb2
    Group By tlb2.BarCode
    UNION
    Select tlb3.BarCode As BarCode, Sum(0) As TotalIncomes,
      Sum(0) As TotalOutcomes, Sum(IfNull(tlb3.Adjustment,
      0)) As TotalAdjustments
    From stock_adjustments tlb3
    Group By tlb3.BarCode
    UNION
    Select tlb4.BarCode As BarCode, Sum(0) As TotalIncomes,
      Sum(0) As TotalOutcomes, Sum(0) As TotalAdjustments
    From stock_outcomes tlb4

    Group By tlb4.BarCode) As tlb_all
Group By tlb_all.BarCode
Having IsNull(tlb_all.BarCode) = FALSE And Leftover <> 0
Order By tlb_all.BarCode
```

Comment: It seems that this may be able to be accomplished using with rollup or group by grouping sets.  syntax depends on the RDBMS.  I'm guessing this is mysql but can you confirm?

Comment: Yup.  MySQL doesn't support subqueries in the `from` clause.  It is in the documentation:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html.  You can do this by creating one view for the inner subquery and then another view for the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table of all the possible codes, you can do something like this::

```
select bc.BarCode,
       (Select Sum(si.Quantity) From stock_incomes si where si.BarCode = bc.BarCode
       ) as TotalIncomes,
       . . .
from BarCodes bc
```

That is, move the subqueries to the `select` clause (these are allowed).